# read text document from scanned image

Tags: programming-languages, jpeg, ocr

Is there any way we can get the text from a scanned document in jpg jpeg or any other format ? I am using ruby as my programming language . But I guess if I can get the texts with some help from other programming languages , it will not be much of a problem to integrate.

Thanks.

Comment: wiki OCR,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an OCR library. There are additional details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085/free-ocr-library.

In brief, you may wish to consider using tessnet (http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/).

Answer (score 1):

This technology is called optical character recognition (OCR).

For programming, [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373949/extract-text-from-images-programmatically), which recommends [tesseract-ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).

[OCR for ruby? check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877206/using-ruby-and-ubuntu-with-optical-character-recognition).

If it's just a couple images, [here's a site that supposedly does it for free](http://www.free-ocr.com/).

Answer (score 0):

OCR Terminal http://www.ocrterminal.com has been the best (most accurate) free tool out of at least a dozen that I have used.  It works especially well with formatted (table) data.

Comment: It's works online. You can't use it as an embedded part of the program.